# Turn off delete confirmation in table view cell after tap on the deletion control

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

In my `tableView` I use editing mode for deleting and inserting rows. When I tap on delete, the "delete" button appears on the right of the cell. I want to delete the cell immediately without confirmation.

Is there any way to **turn off** this delete confirmation after tapping on deletion control?

[image: button]

I want to remove this delete confirmation button.

Comment: Don’t use editing mode. Instead implement the swipe action to delete.

Comment: @vadian unfortunately this is the type of editing I need

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I didn't find any good native solution for this problem. I solved this problem by custom UIButton which I placed in my custom uitableViewcell, which triggers deletion of the row.